# Retrieve previous text before `ansible- blockinfile` updates it

Tags: ansible

I use `blockinfile` to add some lines to a file (for example `.bashrc`) which works as expected (with a custom marker).

I can print a message if the block changed and the file changed (updated), but how can I get the previous value?

The use case is: I have several systems and I want this file to be the same everywhere; if a change is done on one box, I need to get the (locally changed) value back to distribute it later to the other boxes.

How to get the current value (i.e. the value before the change) back?

Comment: I tested that. You can `register` the result of `blockinfile` and that var contains a dict `diff` with a key `before` and `after`. They are empty by default. But if you ran the playbook with --`diff` they contain the value before - but when I'm right the complete file. So - now - there is no "one-liner" for that problem.  Only solution would be - copy the file before blockinfile (backup: true) and compare that file with the new one in a second call (there is no module diff).

Comment: Is the file exactly the same on all the boxes? I meant if it's exactly the same, why not copy the file overall hosts instead of modifying them?

Comment: Could you just use the `fetch` module to make a local copy of the file before your `blockinfile` task modifies it?

Comment: @larsks - I think this is the idea: fetch the file before the blockfile call. if it is not updated (i.e. the same as before) then delete the fetched file. I hoped for something better, buth thank you for the idea, i will try it!

Comment: @ikora - the local changes are just done on the box where the need occurred but should then automatically spread to all the others. I hate to work on one box and then find out that something I changed on another one has to repeated here (and remember what the change exactly was?).

Answer (score 0):

The current solution, which can be improved, is a list of tasks which is included with `include_tasks`. It is looped over all user accounts.

```
- name: make local copy of current bashrc
  become: true 
  copy: 
    remote_src: yes
    src: "/home/{{item}}/.bashrc"
    dest: "/home/{{item}}/.bashrc.current"

- name: Add text at end of bashrc
  become: true
  blockinfile: 
    path: "/home/{{item}}/.bashrc" 
    block: "{{lookup('file', 'bashrc_additions.sh')}}" 
    backup: yes # what is the name?
    create: no 
    state: present
    marker: "# {mark} ANSIBLE {{ansible_role_name}} MANAGED BLOCK"

  register: bashrc_updated

- name: action when changed
  block:
    - debug: 
        var:  bashrc_updated 

    - debug:
        msg: 
          - bashrc_updated - original is fetched to role. 
          - compare if changed, delete if same as previous target
          - file "{{roleFilesDir}}bashrc_currentChanged_{{ ansible_hostname }}_{{ item }}" 
             
    - name: fetch original bashr if it was changed
      fetch: 
        src: "/home/{{item}}/.bashrc.current"  # isthis bak?
        dest: "{{roleFilesDir}}bashrc_currentChanged_{{ ansible_hostname }}_{{ item }}" 
              # in ansiblehost on controller
        flat: yes
  when: bashrc_updated.changed |bool
```

Additionally, one could save the updated file and compare it the next time with the current one to detect if there are any local updates.